# Variables in a IIFE

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to understand closures in Javascript. I came across this example :

```
var add = (function () {
  var counter = 0;
  return function () {counter += 1; return counter}
})();

add();
add();
add();
```

I do not understand why counter value comes to be 3. I can clearly see that counter is being intialized with 0 each time the function is called.

Comment: You're calling the inner function multiple times, not the outer one. The outer one is being immediately invoked, which sets `counter = 0`, and `add` to the inner function that gets returned

Comment: I want to know how things are happening under the hood. How the javascript engine is working? Can you please refer me to a more detailed example or article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at what gets interpreted in which order.

- Step #1:
  In `var add = (something)()`, the first thing to be evaluated is the "something".
- Step #2:
  Once evaluated as a valid function, there is a reference to it which is not yet stored in a variable and never will because the function is getting executed right away due to the second set of parenthesis.
- Step #3:
  That function does 2 things:
  1) it assigns `0` to the `counter` variable.
  2) it declares another function: `function () {counter += 1; return counter}`. The reference to that function is what will be assigned to the `add` variable.
- Step #4:
  So each times `add()` is called, what is executed is `counter += 1; return counter`.

Scope:
The `counter` variable only exist in the outer and inner functions. The outer function never had its reference stored to a variable because it was immediately called, so it never will be called again. The inner function reference was stored in `add` and can be called again.

```js
var add = (function () {
  var counter = 0;
  return function () {counter += 1; return counter}
})();

// Notice that add is the "inner" function
console.log(add)

// What is returned by add is the counter value
var firstCall = add();
var secondCall = add();
var thirdCall = add();
console.log(firstCall, secondCall, thirdCall)

// the counter does not exist outside the scope of the inner function
console.log(typeof(counter))
```

A good reference I can suggest to learn more about how JS is interpreted is [Wakata.io](https://wakata.io/learn)... Particularly the [CompuThink](https://wakata.io/learn/info/computhink) section for your question.

Answer (score 0):

The function within the parentheses, followed by another pair of parentheses is an IIFE - immediately invoked function expression.

```js
//immediately invoked function expression

(function() {
  var counter = 0;
  return function() {
    counter += 1;
    return counter;
  }
})();
```

This is called so because this function gets called immediately after it is defined.

The variable add is not assigned the IIFE. Rather, it gets the result of the invoked function as below.

```js
function() {
  counter += 1;
  return counter;
}
```

A closure is the means by which a function has access to the scope in which it is created.

This function has access to counter variable in the IIFE because of closure behaviour. Even though IIFE's life time is already over, the function in add variable has access to it due to closure.

Whenever we are calling add(), it is actually updating the counter in IIFE. All the while, IIFE was never executed again. It ran only once during the initial phase.